# Most performant way to check if any row returned from a query is contained within a string?

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm implementing a name filter where a table "name_filter" with a single column "filter" is populated with words which are deemed inappropriate. When a name is requested I want to check to see if any name within this table is contained within the requested name using `*row*` matching.

The query is:

```
SELECT filter
FROM name_filter
```

I am currently pulling the entire column and then performing a check one-by-one using the `find()` method of `std::string`:

```
// Check all names in the filter table and match if the input name contains the
// value in one of the rows
for (int i = 0; i < affectedRows; ++i) {
   MYSQL_ROW row = mysql_fetch_row(result);

   // No more rows
   if (!row)
      break;

   // Content matches name filter
   if (name.find(row[0]) != std::string::npos) {
      mysql_free_result(result);

      return false;
   }
}
```

A friend suggested the following query but wasn't sure if it was correct. It SEEMS to work but neither one of us have done a query like this before:

```
SELECT filter
FROM name_filter
WHERE 'name'
LIKE concat('%',filter,'%')
LIMIT 1
```

Will this work for all cases? Please include a description of WHY it works with this query.

Ideally, I would like for the comparison to have been a `REGEX`. Although not part of the actual question, brownie points for an alternative proposal that works as `REGEX` instead of `LIKE`.

The case for REGEX would be to disallow short names like ^bra$ but still allow Cobra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, according to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html), this is exactly what you want to do:

> To find names containing a w:
>
> `mysql> SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name LIKE '%w%';`

However, there are two subtle differences compared to your `c++`-code:

- if your filter contains a `null` (not the string `'null'`, but something like a `null`-pointer in `c++`), `like` will not find it, while your `c++` code will not allow it (as `null` is casted to an empty string `''`).
- if your filter contains the operators `_` or `%`, they will be interpreted as "one character" and "any number of characters", while `string.find` does not do that. So if you have a filter with `z%o`, the name `Zhro` would be forbidden, because it would match `%z%o%`.

You can of course use the last point to your advantage, and instead of adding the partial word to the list, add the whole search expression. If you e.g. add `%bra%` to your filterlist,

```
SELECT * FROM pet WHERE 'name' LIKE filter;
```

will then find any words containing `bra`. If you would add `bra%` to your filterlist, it would forbid `bra` (and `brainiac`), but not forbid `Cobra`. If you add `bra`, this would forbid `bra`, but neither `Cobra` nor `brainiac`. This list might be a bit harder to maintain until you are used to it, but will give you more flexibility.

You can do the same with regpatterns (note the missing `%`):

> To find names containing a w, use this query:
>
> `mysql> SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name REGEXP 'w';`

[Regular expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) support the usual operators like `^` and `$`. While regular expressions support more operators than `like`, these two can also be expressed using `like` by not using a leading or trailing `%`. If your filterwords contain regexp operators (like `^` or `.`), these will be interpreted as well - which you can again use to your advantage if you enter your filters as regular expressions.

To prevent the complete word `bra` but still allow e.g. `Cobra` (but also `sexy_bra`), you can use any of the following:

```
SELECT * FROM name_filter WHERE 'name' REGEXP '^bra$';
SELECT * FROM name_filter WHERE 'name' LIKE 'bra';
SELECT * FROM name_filter WHERE 'name' = 'bra';
```

The last one will not interprete operators, so `SELECT * FROM name_filter WHERE 'Zhro' = 'z%o';` will not be `true`.